# Does Dropbox accesstoken has expiration? Can I use Android Core API to automatically log in Dropbox and get new accesstoken?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have some questions during I work on the app with Dropbox Core API.

First, Does Dropbox accesstoken has expiration? I have used Facebook sdk before, I remember the Facebook accesstoken has expiration, so I need to write a function to refresh Facebook accesstoken. I've already read the documentation of Dropbox CORE API, but it seems the accesstoken expiration happens if user unlink the Dropbox or Dropbox revoke the accesstoken, they doesn's mention if the accesstoken expires itself or not.

Second, I'm using CORE API to log in Dropbox and get accesstoken. Is there any way to use CORE AI to log in Dropbox automatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can find information about Dropbox API access token expiration here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/support#token-expiration

In short, it effectively doesn't expire.

You can't log in to Dropbox and get an access token automatically. The user needs to process the app authorization flow and explicitly authorize your app, but once they do you can store and re-use the resulting access token.